# Размер текста и цифр

Tags: html, css, scss

Задача заключается в том, чтобы сделать цифры в строке  `font-size: 60px;` а текст `font-size: 18px` без использования обёртки по типу `<span>, <b>`  и тому подобных

Comment: Никак. В CSS нет ничего такого для обработки этих ситуаций. Теги SCSS и HTML тут вообще не при чем

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить вариант с использованием [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/::after), [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/content) и [attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Обратите внимание, что функция `attr` поддерживается далеко не всеми браузерами

```css
.amount {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.amount::after {
  content: attr(data-pcs);
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="amount" data-pcs="штук">100</div>
```